# Country is selected as "All" calculate a specific column value only

Tags: powerbi

Need some advise on how to filter data when in "Country" column is selected as "All" then consider only specific value which is in different column(Raw) else calculate respective values(column Coverage) for respective Countries

There are 3 columns - Country, Coverage and Raw

Basically when selected as "ALL" it considers total of coverage column but I want it to consider a single value from Raw column[image]

Note - I'm using this in Line chart in Power BI

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: can you post a pbi file with example data?  or paste in a grab of your table(s).  To better help you we need to see how your tables and data are layed out.

Comment: @Taterhead thank you for looking into. I've attached the image of my data table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create measures that have different behaviors for different filter conditions using functions like `ISFILTERED` or `HASONEVALUE`. For example:

```
Measure = IF(ISFILTERED(Table1[Country]), <Calculation 1>, <Calculation 2>)
```

or

```
Measure = IF(HASONEVALUE(VALUES(Table1[Country])), <Calculation 2>, <Calculation 1>)
```

Comment: what should I write in <calculation 1>, <calculation 2> ?

Comment: @3689 I can't tell from the information you've provided. You haven't given input and output specifications descriptive enough that people can help.